# MySQL - Unique Confirmed Emails

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a project on `Yii2` and I want to fix a bug in registration form.
This is my `user_profile` table:

```
id | email | email_confirmed
____________________________
1  | a@b.c | 0
```

I have a unique index on email column and when user confirm his/her email address, `email_confirmed` column will be 1.

Now here is the problem:
If user 1 do not confirm his/her email, no one else can register that email.

One solution came to my mind is removing unique index and handle it by PHP. But it's not suit me for best. I want to know is there any better solution with MySql?

Comment: `If user 1 do not confirm his/her email, no one else can register that email.` I think this is the desired behavior. Once an email is used, no one else can use it again regardless of whether it was confirmed or not.

Comment: It is weird to have an extra registration with the same email address and with a confirmed signal. Do you think that would make sense?

Comment: You could add a timestamp column and remove unconfirmed addresses after a period

Answer (score 2):

You could use function index to handle partial indexes(MySQL 8.0.13 and newer):

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS    SELECT 1 id, 'a@b.c' email,  0 AS email_confirmed
UNION SELECT 2 id, 'a@b.c' email,  1 AS email_confirmed;
```

And index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_t ON t((CASE WHEN email_confirmed = 1 THEN email END));
```

Trying to insert another occurence of email that is confirmed:

```
INSERT INTO t(id, email, email_confirmed) VALUES (3, 'a@b.c', 1);
-- Duplicate entry 'a@b.c' for key 'uq_t'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4c404a4033bb025a5a1f16b1600916c)**

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I got this error:
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CASE WHEN `email_confirmed` = 1 THEN `email` END))' at line 1. 
my Mysql version is 5.7.

Comment: @MortezaPouretemadi MySQL 8.0.13

Comment: @MortezaPouretemadi Really? Downvote? For providing alternative. Sure you have full right to do so but you should tag your question with correct version upfront

Comment: I'm sorry. I was going to remove my upvote. but unfortunately it happened this way and I could not to undo it.